# Guava toJavaUtil() does not exists

Tags: java, guava

I have upgraded my project and now it does not find the  `toJavaUtil()` method. I think it is no longer supported in the newer version. How can I change the method to work the same without this call?

```
private ViewFlightLevel toActualFlightLevel(... source) {
        return source.getActualTimeOver()
                .toJavaUtil()
                .map(actualTime -> ....)
                .orElse(null);
    }
```

**getActualTimeOver** :

```
@Nonnull
    public Optional<Instant> getActualTimeOver() {
        return Optional.fromNullable(actualTimeOver);
    }
```

**toJavaUtil()**

```
 public java.util.Optional<T> toJavaUtil() {
        return java.util.Optional.ofNullable(this.orNull());
    }
```

My guava version:

```
<library.guava-testlib.version>19.0</library.guava-testlib.version>
```

Comment: can you share details of what has been upgraded ? which libraries are changed ?

Comment: @Aditya I have upgraded whole BOM, so I can not say what was changed exactly. I tried to build project and it does not see  this method so I think it is not supported anymore. If I go to Optional by guava, then I can see that there is no such a method.

Comment: the actual method doesn't look like it'll change with an upgrade considering it uses java.util classes. If you can provide some more code here it might help

Comment: @Aditya Tbh, I do not know which code as I have already provided method which is used and mtehod that calls it. I have provided also `toJavaUtil()` method.

Comment: can you share the type of source ?

Comment: The method was added in [v`21.0`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/551207b426314b599927de21afc6ae51698cbf3b/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Optional.java#L139).

Answer (score 1):

Its work for me with the latest version: 28.1-jre

```
fun main() {
    val a: java.util.Optional<String> =
           com.google.common.base.Optional.of("String")
           .toJavaUtil()
}
```

Comment: Also, check the Java version to be 1.8 or higher

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output! [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

> this.orNull()

should provide the value or null if it doesn't exist.

If you can use streams, do that. Else the method could be re-written avoiding Guava as

```
private ViewFlightLevel toActualFlightLevel(... source) {
    if (source.ActualTimeOver() == null) {
        return null;
    }
    //Assuming the mapping method is - toViewFlightLevel
    return toViewFlightLevel(actualTime);
}
```

Can only give you a full proof answer if the type of source and the mapping function definitions are provided.

Comment: but I have .`orElse(null)`

Comment: If the optional has an output, it will return that, else it will return null. It exists so that functional interfaces don't require null checks at each stage.
In this case, if the toViewFlightLevel method returns null toActualFlightLevel also returns null. The behaviour should remain same as before. Can you test and see ?

Comment: Is there any option to do this without additional method (toViewFlightLevel), but with streams?

Comment: you need to provide the details of what is happening in -  .map(actualTime -> ....)
The method is just a place holder for whatever is happening in that mapper